# How do I display correct html symbols from JSON with react native

Tags: react-native

I am using an API to pull a short description and title. In some of the titles are &*trade; and they are not displaying correctly. (the star is not there)

```
<Text 
    style={styles.descr}
     numberOfLines ={3}>
      {result.shortDescription}
</Text>
```

//output 
$22.95 Choice&*trade;
blah blah blah

How would I go about displaying the TM symbol or Copyright symbol?

Comment: displaying Choice&*trade; without star

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
import {Html5Entities} from 'html-entities'
const ResultDetail = ({ result }) => {
const entities = new Html5Entities()

return (
<Text
style={styles.descr}
numberOfLines ={3}>
{entities.decode(result.shortDescription)}/>
</Text>
)
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Answer (score 0):

Normally **Superscript** tag sets the half of character above on the text writing line like <sup>**TM**</sup>

You can use `lineHeight` style attribute to make Superscript text as below,

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, lineHeight: 30 }}>$22.95 Choice </Text>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, lineHeight: 18 }}>TM</Text>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, lineHeight: 30 }}> blah blah blah</Text>
</View>
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: is it okay to print simply "TM" and make some css changes, not bad coding?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your comment. could you be more specific

Comment: printing "TM" with some css tricks  without using unicode charecter or HTML is a good coding?

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Comment: not worried about lineheight i am just not getting any TM to begin with from the JSON i am getting &*trade; without the star

Answer (score 0):

By Using HTML Entities

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ "__html": "&copy;" }} />
```

with unicode character

```
    let results = [%raw {|'\u00a9'|}];
     <span> {results } </span>
```

Comment: <Text 
        style={styles.descr}
        numberOfLines ={3}><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{'__html': result.shortDescription}}>
        </span></Text>

this is not working

Comment: what output your getting?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JY2A68V.png
desired would be Choice&trade; with symbol

Comment: if i'm understood correctly you want copyright symbol right? i don't get &* without asterisk thing... can you please elaborate more? however copyright symbol can easily print using above code.

Comment: I would like all symbols to appear correctly, TM, Copyright, etc. I put the * in the line to stop it from autoformatting to the TM symbol in my example.